# Optimize a Max() and DENSE_RANK Analytical Query for a Cursor

Tags: sql, oracle, cursor, analytical

I have a query that is taking a long time (187.42 seconds) to find all related documents containing an attribute (c.scr) and from that list giving me the document processed with the latest document date. I was wondering if anyone could provide any suggestions to optimize the query.

Please note, I did play around with ROW_NUMBER, RANK and DENSE_RANK and they were even slower so this is the best I got so far.

```
       (Query) total time '187.42 seconds':

              SELECT MAX(A.DOC_NUM) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY A.DOC_DT DESC) as DOC_NUM
              FROM AB A , CD C 
              WHERE A.ID = C.ID
              AND SUBSTR(C.SCR,20,8) = '123123123';


      (Data Set) : 

              DOC_NUM             DOC_DT
              AB201201230000058 JAN-23-12
              AB201206280000674 JUN-28-12
              AB201406230000066 AUG-05-14
              AB201406230000066 AUG-05-14
              AB201312170000227 DEC-17-13
              AB201312180000093 DEC-19-13
```

Thanks,

Comment: Biggest thing that jumps out to me is the `Where` clause: `SUBSTR(C.SCR,20,8) = '123123123'` cannot use any index (assuming you have one) with this statement.

Comment: Sure it can ... a function-based one. The question is, though, if such an index would be useful (LIO-wise).

Answer (score 1):

You could try doing it this way:

```
SELECT A.*
FROM (SELECT A.DOC_NUM
      FROM AB A JOIN
           CD C 
           ON A.ID = C.ID
      WHERE SUBSTR(C.SCR, 20, 8) = '123123123'
      ORDER BY A.DOC_DT DESC
     ) A
WHERE rownum = 1;
```

You can then speed this up in various ways.  Indexes might help (if there aren't any).  Also, because you are looking for the most recent document, then reducing the result set might help:

```
SELECT A.*
FROM (SELECT A.DOC_NUM
      FROM AB A JOIN
           CD C 
           ON A.ID = C.ID
      WHERE SUBSTR(C.SCR, 20, 8) = '123123123' AND A.DOC_DT >= sysdate - 30
      ORDER BY A.DOC_DT DESC
     ) A
WHERE rownum = 1;
```

If you know a document is added at least once per month.

Comment: So running that query actually got done in at a slower time of 199.52. I suspect that not knowing if that column is indexed will be the answer to see if I can make it quicker.